# Python: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, arrays, loops, tuples

So, I have an array that has been evaluated through a number of equations. Here is all of my code.

```
os.chdir( path )
data = np.load('msii_phasespace.npy',mmap_mode='r')
# data.size: 167197
# data.shape: (167197,)
# data.dtype: dtype([('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4'),
  # ('velx', '<f4'), ('vely', '<f4'), ('velz', '<f4'), ('m200', '<f4')])

##############################################################################

## Non-constant
M = data['m200'] # kg // Mass of dark matter haloes

R = [] # Km // Radius of sphere 
for masses in M:
    R.append(((3*masses)/(RHO_C*4*(3.14))**(1.0/3.0)))

kR = []
for radii in R:
    kR.append(k*radii)
```

I have constants, but they are not really worth mentioning

```
def T(k): # Fitting Function // Assuming a lambdaCDM model
    q = k/((OMEGA_M)*H**2)*((T_CMB)/27)**2
    L = np.log(euler+1.84*q)
    C = 14.4 + 325/(1+60.5*q**1.11)
    return L/(L+C*q**2)

##############################################################################

def P(k): # Linear Power Spectrum
    A = 0.75 # LambdaCDM Power Normalization
    n = 0.95 # current constraints from WMAP+LSS
    return A*k**n*T(k)**2

##############################################################################

W = [] # Fourier Transfrom in the top hat function
for values in kR:
   W.append(((3*(np.sin(values)-values*np.cos(values)))/(values)**(3)))
```

## *** My real question comes to this part of my code.***

```
integral1 = []
for values1 in W:
    k1 = lambda k: k**2*P(k)*values1**2
    integral1.append(integrate.quad(k1, 0, np.Inf))
```

I have a integrated every value of the Fourier array, W, to a new array, integral1, that is evaluating P(k), k, and W all in respect to k (hopefully correctly).

[image]

where k is defined constant.

The integral is a part of function called the mass variance where

[image]

```
sigma = [] # Mass Varience
for values2 in integral1:
    norm1 = 1/(2*np.pi**2)
    sigma.append((norm1*values2)**(0.5))
```

I'm trying to create a new array, sigma, using the mass variance for each value in what I defined as integral1.

My problem is that when applying the for loop on this array does not suffice in my attempts with this array in comparisons to my other for loops.

I keep getting the error `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Hopefully, as long as as the rest of my code is correct, their has to be a solution to fixing this. I just don't know what to do at this point.

If I have left any information out in this post, please inform me, and I will do my best to add whatever is needed to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `*` operator on a tuple you aren't doing scalar multiplication of each item in a vector, you are repeating the tuple by the operand on the right side:

```
>>> (4, 5, 6) *3
(4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6)
```

Do do a multiplication you could do a list comprehension like this:

```
[i * 3 for i  in (4, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: I tried a list comprehension like so. Still yielded the same TypeError. I've edited my post to make it more clearer what i want to accomplish.

Comment: @DarthLazar Can you provide the values that are in `integral1`?

Comment: The values are just a very large array on numbers. The array is 167197 in size. In all honesty, it is a lot of values to provide you with. So here is a sample `(1.0149019539104172e-28, 1.81888431498184e-28), (5.242726709577474e-29, 9.395896168142101e-29)`, and so on.

Comment: So it is a list of tuples? And you want each value in each tuple to be multiplied by `norm1` and raised to 1/2?

Comment: I just realized something. So my values of W are all displayed as an array. When trying to integrate each value in W, I does not appear to output out an array, but something else, I think a tuple. Is there anyway of correcting that?

Comment: Perhaps instead of `integral.append()` you want `integral.extend()`,

Comment: wow, brilliant my friend. You always learn something new everyday! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sequence is a list object, to multiple a constant(or scalar) by a list(vector), you will need to use something like

```
k=10
arr=[1,2,3,4]
newarr=map(lambda x: k*x, arr)
```

Alternatively, it might be worth using numpy to get these functions in by default.